# how to cancel the earlier fetch request and keep the last one during search

Tags: reactjs

```js
const controller = new AbortController()
const signal = controller.signal
const Search = ({ searchSuggestion }) => {
    const onkeychange = async (e) => {
        controller.abort()
        let string = e.target.value
        const suggest = await getSearchSuggestion({
            string,
            signal,
        })

    }
    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            autoComplete="off"
            placeholder="Search"
            onChange={onkeychange}
        />
    )
}
```

This canceling request code. The problem with this is, it cancel all the requests. While I only want to cancel requests of earlier keystrokes. And keep the last request alive.

Comment: is it possible to have codesanbox or codepen demo for this ?
You are very close.

Comment: what you asking for is called debouncing - it means that until user stop typing no request is being even made https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the same controller/signal in all requests, you can save the previous controller like this :

```
const Search = ({ searchSuggestion }) => {
    const previousController = useRef();
    const onkeychange = async (e) => {
        if (previousController.current) {
          previousController.current.abort();
        }
        let string = e.target.value
        const controller = new AbortController()
        const signal = controller.signal
        previousController.current = controller;
        const suggest = await getSearchSuggestion({
            string,
            signal,
        })

    }
    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            autoComplete="off"
            placeholder="Search"
            className="search"
            onChange={onkeychange}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: can we const previousController twice in the code ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have one signal that is connected to all of your fetch requests. If you want to cancel only the last one, you should pass for every single fetch request new instance of `AbortController` and when you do the `abort()`, you should do that only on the `AbortController` instances that you want.

Comment: Lazar Nikolic is right. Just put  `controller` and `signal` inside of your search function

Comment: put the controller and signal inside search function doesnt work. it cancel everything as well